Xamarin.Forms iOS broken after updating Xcode from 15 to 16.1
I have a macOS updated to 15.1.1 with Xcode 16.1.
On Windows 11 machine I am running Visual Studio 2022 17.12.1 with latest Xamarin.Forms.
I try to debug Xamarin.Forms iOS app through macOS on USB connected iPhone Xr 17.6.1. I am able to successfully connect the macOS through Visual Studio.
However, after successful build, at point of deploying app package to iPhone I get this error:
Failed to install application on device iPhone Xr: error HE0004: Could not load the framework 'IDEDistribution' (path: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/IDEDistribution.framework/Versions/A/IDEDistribution)


I have found solution here:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-117599/Could-not-load-the-framework-IDEDistribution-on-MacOS-15.0#focus=Comments-27-10817458.0-0
A small difference for me was, that I typed wrongly sudo password and did not have permission to copy files over via Terminal.
You can do the same file copying via Finder too and it works fine.
